# Change keyboard shorcut for switching desktop workspaces

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

I am working on MacOS `Sierra` and wanted change desktop workspaces quickly.
For this, I used the keyboard shortcut under `Mission Control` and selected all the `tick boxes` for `Switch to Desktop N`.

The shortcut key for this was ^1.

Another shortcut is `ctrl+ ->/<-`. But,  I wanted to change it to `alt+->/<-` so that it can be done **single-handedly**. How should I do this?

**EDIT**:  I want to use only the `right alt` and not `left alt` for the above purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you can go to the `Preferences System`, then `Keyboard`, then to the `Shortcuts` tab.

From here,

1. You select the line you want to change the shortcut of
2. You click on the icon showing the current shortcut
3. You execute the new shortcut to record it

[image: Shortcut]

PS: I'm not sure if this is what you intended to do.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do that but what if I want to use only the `right alt`  and not `left alt` for the above purpose.

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi If you want the `right alt` key to change Desktop, but not the `left alt` key, I don't get why, but anyway, you can do it with the following:  Reset the default keys with the `ctrl` key in the keyboard preferences. Then remap the `right alt` key to the `left ctrl` key with Karabiner-Elements for Mac.